# Mixed Content... requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest has been blocked

Tags: magento-1.9, https, xmlhttprequest

I have been looking for this for weeks.  I just can't seem to find where this mixed content is coming from.  In the error below it always says the mixed content is my root domain name i.e., http://www.example.com/.

My site is all ssl frontend and back.  I have everything being redirected to the https version.

Here is the error in Chrome developer tools:

**Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/some-category/etc-product.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.example.com/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS**.

What would I search for??  I'm sure it's some kind of variable.  I really don't know.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I found was an old htaccess rule before I changed to all SSL. It was this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.11\.11\.11
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

After deleting it everything worked fine.